# Writing to a .doc file

Tags: java, utf-8, doc

I am trying to write an Arabic sentence to .doc file. But each time I open the .doc file it shows a message that says file conversion and it asks in which Unicode I want to show the .doc file so I keep the Unicode(UTF-8) and everything goes okay.

Here's the code where I write to the file:

```
PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(newFile+".doc", true));
print.println(toString());
print.println();
print.close();
```

Where `newFile` is the file chosen by the user (no extension added from the user) and  `toString()` is a function that combines the whole sentence to be written on the file.

My problem is, do I have to see this file conversion each time I open the .doc file?

I already tried to open properties of the project in net beans and put coding : UTF-8!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Any API are you using OR simple File IO?

Comment: How do you write the .doc file? Do you use POI or any other library? If not, then you're *almost certainly* doing it wrong.

Comment: Okay, here's the code where I write to the file :

PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(newFile+".doc", true));  
            print.println(toString());
            print.println();
            print.close();

Where newFile is the file chosen by the user ( no extension added from the user ), toSting() is a function that combines the whole sentence to be written on the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not writing a `.doc` file. You're writing a simple text file and call it `.doc`.

For it to work as a `.doc` file, you need to write code that actually writes the `.doc` file format (or use a library such as [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to do it for you.

If Word finds a file that's not a `.doc` file it tries to interpret it as a text file, but needs to know the encoding, that's why you get the dialog.